Add counts (n) above stacked bars in ggplot in R
I want to add an (n=xxx) count for the total number of values in each bar above each bar on my plot. I have calculated the counts in the total_counts dataframe.
I've tried using geom_text to add the labels, but I cannot get the labels to sit above the bars themselves without causing rescaling of the y axis to include the label values, which compresses the bars down.
I wonder if anyone who is ggplot expert may be able to help please?
The dummy data frame can be downloaded from my google drive (https://shorturl.at/YphZ7)
# Import dummy_data.csv from your own path

# Calculate total counts for each predictor level
total_counts <- aggregate(outcome ~ predictor, data = dummy_data, FUN = length)
colnames(total_counts) <- c("predictor", "count")

# Plot
ggplot(dummy_data, aes(x = predictor, fill = outcome)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  labs(y = "Proportion", x = "predictor ", fill = "Outcome") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle("Distribution of outcome across predictor Levels")


To get it to work with position fill in stead of stacked, use
ggplot(dummy_data, aes(x = predictor, group= outcome, fill = outcome)) +
geom_bar(position = "fill") +
geom_text(data = total_counts, aes( fill = NULL, group = NULL, x = predictor, label = count, y = 1), vjust = -1)
